# I need to send push notification after something added to firebase database how can i do that

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

I have done this referring to above blog.

Below code for creating database in firebase :

```
public static void sendNotificationToUser(String user, final String message) {
        DatabaseReference ref;
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference notifications = ref.child("notificationRequests");

        Map notification = new HashMap<>();
        notification.put("username", user);
        notification.put("message", message);

        notifications.push().setValue(notification);
    }
```

This is my index.js script code :

```
var firebase = require('firebase-admin');
var request = require('request');

var API_KEY = ".AAAA6J9B3gg:APA91bEw_oHJSrAFuRxB6k6TzJ6wU-yzEw64yaf7CwBq7ur2iroGqi7Cf5JZ127wW_sBFtfdtBkpz15pPTVdQtkGPoMf6uBTMgq5AdTwXVWUDhtxQiGx5Pkj2CIpPDi0xTNT_ZMiEmIG";

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://chitchatapp-73060.firebaseio.com/"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
    var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
    requests.on('child_added', function (requestSnapshot) {
        var request = requestSnapshot.val();
        sendNotificationToUser(
            request.username,
            request.message,
            function () {
                requestSnapshot.ref.remove();
            }
        );
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
    request({
        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': ' application/json',
            'Authorization': 'key=' + API_KEY
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            notification: {
                title: message
            },
            to: '/topics/user_' + username
        })
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) { console.error(error); }
        else if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
            console.error('HTTP Error: ' + response.statusCode + ' - ' + response.statusMessage);
        }
        else {
            onSuccess();
        }
    });
}
listenForNotificationRequests();
```

When I try to deploy this it gives an error like below :

> Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'request'

Comment: Hey ! You can't update your question after I resolved the first issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the **request** module ?

```
npm install request
```

[Npm install documentation.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: can u tell me how to give path to service account .json

Comment: You can download this file from your project settings on Firebase website. Put this file in a private folder for example and the path will be `private/serviceAccountKey.json`

Comment: i gave my path like this C:/Users/user/CSApplication/functions/private/google-services.json now its giving a error like this  Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Comment: im sorry but i accepted ur answer. its in the function folder i user like u said but it giving me error that Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

Comment: I recommend you to reset your question with your previous issue, and create a new question, I think Frank van Puffelen the author of the article will answered you.

Comment: i add another question but no one answering it